# Augmented Reality SDK with OpenCV

Tags: opencv, augmented-reality

I am developing an Augmented Reality SDK on OpenCV. I had some problems to find tutorials on the topic, which steps to follow, possible algorithms, fast and efficient coding for real-time performance etc.

So far I have gathered the next information and useful links.

## OpenCV installation

Download [latest release version](http://opencv.org/downloads.html).

You can find installation guides [here](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/table_of_content_introduction/table_of_content_introduction.html) (platforms: linux, mac, windows, java, android, iOS).

Online [documentation](http://opencv.org/documentation.html).

## Augmented Reality

For begginers [here](http://dsynflo.blogspot.com.es/2010/06/simplar-augmented-reality-for-opencv.html) is a simple augmented reality code in OpenCV. It is a good start.

For anyone searching for a well designed state-of-the-art SDK I found some general steps that every augmented-reality based on marker tracking should have, considering OpenCV functions.

1. Main program: creates all classes, initialization, [capture](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10697379/744859) frames from video.
2. AR_Engine class: Controls the parts of an augmented reality application. There should be 2 main states:

   - **detection**: tries to detect the marker in the scene
   - **tracking**: once it is detected, uses lower computational techniques for traking the marker in upcoming frames.

Also there should be some algorithms for finding the position and orientation of the camera in every frame. This is achieve by detecting the homography transformation between the marker detected in the scene, and a 2D image of the marker we have processed offline. The explanation of this method [here](http://cvlab.epfl.ch/~lepetit/papers/lepetit_ftcgv05.pdf) (page 18). The main steps for Pose Estimations are:

1. **Load camera Intrinsic Parameters**. Previously extracted offline through calibration.
   [image: intrinsic parameters]
2. **Load the pattern** (marker) to track: It is an image of the planar marker we are going to track. It is necessary to extract features and generate descriptors ([keypoints](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/features2d/doc/feature_detection_and_description.html#keypoint)) for this pattern so later we can compare with features from the scene. Algorithms for this task:

   - [SIFT](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/nonfree/doc/feature_detection.html#sift)
   - [FAST](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/features2d/doc/feature_detection_and_description.html#fast)
   - [SURF](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/nonfree/doc/feature_detection.html#surf)
3. For every frame update, run a detection algorithm for **extracting features from the scene** and generate descriptors. Again we have several options.

   - SIFT
   - FAST
   - SURF
   - [FREAK](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/features2d/doc/feature_detection_and_description.html#freak): A new method (2012) supossed to be the fastest.
   - [ORB](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/features2d/doc/feature_detection_and_description.html#orb)
4. Find **matches** between pattern and the scene descriptors.

   - [FLANN matcher](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/flann/doc/flann_fast_approximate_nearest_neighbor_search.html#flann-index)
5. Find [Homography](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#findhomography) matrix from those matches. RANSAC can be used before to find inliers/outliers in the set of matches.
6. Extract **Camera Pose** from homography.

   - Sample code on [Pose from Homography](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10781165/744859).
   - Sample code on [Homography from Pose](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10750648/744859).

## Complete examples:

- [aruco](http://sourceforge.net/projects/aruco/)
- [Mastering OpenCV samples](https://github.com/MasteringOpenCV/code)

Comment: Unfortunately, this is "not constructive", are you're looking for suggestions.

Comment: Regarding the installation task, now OpenCV has migrated to GIT, so for downloading the cource code it is necessary to do a "git clone git://code.opencv.org/opencv.git".

Comment: 47 Up-votes yet closed due to silly rules.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Since AR applications often run on mobile devices, you could consider also other features detector/descriptor:

- [FREAK](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/features2d/doc/feature_detection_and_description.html#freak)
- [ORB](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/features2d/doc/feature_detection_and_description.html#orb)

Comment: Thanks! There is also a "fast" version of FAST that runs realtime in mobiles, it is pyramidal and the SIFT descriptors are reduced

Comment: I have got almost perfect results using ORB

Comment: Actually, reading about ORB it says it is a FAST in pyramids

Comment: Freak is the last algorithm to process descriptor on AR. Faster than FAST.

Answer (score 13):

Generally if you can chose the markers you first detect a square target using an edge detector and then either Hough or simply contours - then identify the particular marker from the internal design. Rather than using a general point matcher.

Take a look at [Aruco](http://www.uco.es/investiga/grupos/ava/node/26) for well written example code.

Comment: Yes, the fiducial approach is the simplest, but it is not quite up-to-date. I think now one should point to textured markers. Thanks. The example is very interesting as it is well explained, though.

Comment: If you want to know the pose, you need to match the 3D position of marker features to the corresponding image coords. Regular shaped targets make this easier but they don't need to be planar

Comment: But if they are not planar, you need the 3d-model or a CAD model, otherwise homography from 2d-to-3d is not a valid method anymore, is it? I mean the Direct Linear Transform used in findhomography

Comment: Yes, if you have a 3d marker you need to know the real word 3d shape (from cad, or measuring it) but it does give a better soln