# Augmented Reality Gaming

Tags: image-processing, opencv, augmented-reality

I want to develop a augmented reality game. Player will stand in a room and some cameras will take video of him. Idea is to add a monster to that video which will be seen by player with glasses or direct view from a lcd. Basically this can be done with some image proccessing consept. Adding colored parts or some markers where the monster will be and some hardworking would do that.

But my question is how to make this monster move and as a result have a video which monster looks like attacking the player. Actual game starts after that but I will go step by step. First step is to have that video with attacking monster.

I'm completely new to this , I only used opencv. So I will need some tools to achieve my goal. Where would you suggest me to start? I prefer C++ but any language with some api suggestions are also accepted. I m also open for theoretical, conceptual suggestions. Thank you for reading my question

**Not:** This idea came to my mind after watching anime Sword Art Online. If you like to watch animes and virtual reality stuff; I suggest you to watch it. It is a good one.

Comment: Ahhh sebastian ahhh,  birakmadin su anime isini bi. Bide izleyin die tavsiye verio. Stacoverflow'i emellerine alet etme :) tam turk gibi yorum yazdim stacoverflowa :) neyse bu kadar trolleme yeterli. Kib. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want the monster to move like attacking the player you will need to know the 3D coordinates of the player or some parts of the player. This can be done by making the player wearing recognizable markers that can be detected so homography can be extracted to get the 3D position.

You can start reading this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12283675/744859) on the topic, it is about c++ agugmented reality on OpennCV.

Comment: Alternatively, the he could use a Kinect and Kinect libraries (they're ususally available for most languages and systems now).

Comment: And there is also a new kinect-like opensource developers SDK, but I din't try it so I don't want to talk about it, but the link is [here](http://es.engadget.com/2012/09/13/bitgym-motion-sdk-kinect/) if you want ot have a look.