# Open CV Features Extraction and Image Matching

Tags: image-processing, opencv, textures, shapes

I want to develop an automatic image annotator and an image search application. I have tried using Color Histogram from Open CV's tutorials. It is not giving good results . I used Color Histogram so that I can easily distinguish between night scene or a day scene .

I also want to incorporate shape and texture features for matching images . I did not find anything for extracting shape and texture features from images using Open CV .Please let me know how to extract these features using Open CV or if there is any other library that can hep me in extraction of these features .

I have tried SURF features but for dissimilar images they are not giving good matches .Like two images of Horse in completely different context .

I have a training set of 15K annotated images from the Mir Flick Data Sets and I have a set of around 100 tags . I have read many research papers that give the theoretical approach to this problem but I am unable to implement it.

Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You want to do a lot of difficult things without knowing exactly which approach will you take. I suggest you to start reading this [tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12283675/744859) on the topic.

You need to extract features, get descriptors of those features in order to be recognizable. Then do the matching. From matches you can get 3D position. That is the begining. Once you are able to do that you can focus on more difficult problems.