# OpenCV Computing Camera Position && Rotation

Tags: c++, opencv, camera, rotation, position

for a project I need to compute the real world position and orientation of a camera
with respect to a known object.
I have a set of photos, each displays a chessboard from different points of view.
Using CalibrateCamera and solvePnP I am able to reproject Points in 2d, to get a AR-thing.
So my situation is as such:

- Intrinsic parameters are known
- Distortioncoefficients are known
- translation Vector and rotation Vector are known per photo.

I simply cannot figure out how to compute the position of the camera. My guess was:

- invert translation vector. (=t')
- transform rotation vector to degree (seems to be radian) and invert
- use rodriguez on rotation vector
- compute RotationMatrix * t'

But the results are somehow totally off...
Basically I want to to compute a ray for each pixel in world coordinates.
If more informations on my problem are needed, I'd be glad to answer quickly.

I dont' get it... somehow the rays are still off. This is my Code btw:

```
Mat image1CamPos = tvecs[0].clone(); //From calibrateCamera
Mat rot = rvecs[0].clone(); //From calibrateCamera
Rodrigues(rot, rot);
rot = rot.t();

//Position of Camera
Mat pos = rot * image1CamPos;

//Ray-Normal (( (double)mk[i][k].x) are known image-points)
float x = (( (double)mk[i][0].x) / fx) - (cx / fx);
float y = (( (double)mk[i][0].y) / fy) - (cy / fy);
float z = 1;
float mag = sqrt(x*x + y*y + z*z);
x /= mag;
y /= mag;
z /= mag;

Mat unit(3, 1, CV_64F);
unit.at<double>(0, 0) = x;
unit.at<double>(1, 0) = y;
unit.at<double>(2, 0) = z;

//Rotation of Ray
Mat rot = stof1 * unit;
```

But when plotting this, the rays are off :/

Comment: What in your setup is stationary? The camera or the object?

Comment: the object is a stationary rig.

Comment: This could be a start. http://stackoverflow.com/q/12283675/744859

Comment: Take a look at the source for http://www.uco.es/investiga/grupos/ava/node/26

Comment: I have worked on a similar project and had problems using "solvePnP" (ended up using "POSIT") - did you already somehow verify the results you get from this function?

Comment: With what do you multiply the final `RotationMatrix*t'`? Have you tried the simpler: 1. Rodriguez on rotation vector 2. Construct 4x4 homogeneous transformation matrix from rotation and translation 3. Inverse that 5. Multiply with your (known) object points.

Comment: I am not sure how to build the homogenous matrix out of them. But the final RotationMatrix*t'is the camera Position in world space. (Or object space)

Comment: And yes, solvePnP seems to work. I used it for a small AR-test.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The translation t (3x1 vector) and rotation R (3x3 matrix) of an object with respect to the camera equals the coordinate transformation from object into camera space, which is given by:

```
v' = R * v  + t
```

The inversion of the rotation matrix is simply the transposed:

```
R^-1 = R^T
```

Knowing this, you can easily resolve the transformation (first eq.) to v:

```
v = R^T * v' - R^T * t
```

This is the transformation from camera into object space, i.e., the position of the camera with respect to the object (rotation = `R^T` and translation = `-R^T * t`).

You can simply get a 4x4 homogeneous transformation matrix from this:

```
T = ( R^T  -R^T * t )
    (  0       1    )
```

If you now have any point in camera coordinates, you can transform it into object coordiantes:

```
p' = T * (x, y, z, 1)^T
```

So, if you'd like to project a ray from a pixel with coordinates (a,b) (probably you will need to define the center of the image, i.e. the principal point as reported by `CalibrateCamera`, as (0,0)) -- let that pixel be `P = (a,b)^T`. Its 3D coordinates in camera space are then `P_3D = (a,b,0)^T`. Let's project a ray 100 pixel in positive z-direction, i.e. to the point `Q_3D = (a,b,100)^T`. All you need to do is transform both 3D coordinates into the object coordinate system using the transformation matrix T and you should be able to draw a line between both points in object space. However, make sure that you don't confuse units: CalibrateCamera will report pixel values while your object coordinate system might be defined in, e.g., cm or mm.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much. I believe this is almost what I planned to do. Can I just use the matrix I get from Rodriguez? I was confused, since the rotation vector seems to be in radians.

Comment: Yes, that's the right one. The values of the matrix are neither given as radians nor degrees. You may compute the rotation angle from the matrix, though - if you need to know the angle by that the camera is rotated against the object. Usually, the best solution is to use homogeneous coordinates as this reduces all actions (translation, rotation) to simple matrix multiplications.

Comment: Omg, it is working! Thank you so much, now everything is clear. :)