# Effort for building an Augmented Reality SDK with OpenCV

Tags: opencv, opengl-es, augmented-reality, vuforia, android

Our company is planning to start building some AR apps for Android and iOS. As the first step we need to decide whether we are going to use a Opensource SDK like ARToolKit or to go for a commercialized product like Vuforia, Wikitude, CraftAR, KudanAR etc or whether we should start writing our own AR sdk based on libraries like OpenCV/OpenGL etc..

I have read many articles and comparisons about different SDKs available and have a good idea about what each of them can do and how much they are going to cost. e.g.
http://socialcompare.com/en/comparison/augmented-reality-sdks
https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/dozens-more-augmented-reality-sdks-than-you-think-here-offermann

In the past we have used Vuforia and we have it at the top of our list. But the main issue is the pricing.

So I would like to know if any of you have written or tried to build your own AR sdk based on OpenCV and what type of an effort it will be. To support features like image and 3D object tracking and augmenting 2D and 3D objects. And need to support iOS and Android devices.
This [Augmented Reality SDK with OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12283675/augmented-reality-sdk-with-opencv) has some basic guidelines on how to start.
Mainly what I would like to know is if a software Engineer with about 5+ years of good programming skills try to do this, how much of an effort will that be? Will it be like 1 month work or a 6 months work or even with 12 months of work will it be difficult to get closer to what Vuforia SDK can does?

Comment: I just wonder that why do you want to start from scratch instead of forking an open source project and building on it? I don't have 5+ years exp, but the task is not that hard. However, As you know, creating, optimizing, debugging it and other unpredictable stuff can hurt your project. Don't get me wrong. I am just curious.

Comment: @cagatayodabasi Thanks for the response. Yes that would be an another option. May be we can look at forking ARToolkit. As I have read some limitations about ARToolkit, thought that it might be better to go from the scratch, but yes I think it'll be a good idea to check that option also. Thanks :)